# Can we use "Optional" to do null check in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have very little knowledge on Groovy. I am using `Groovy 2.4.12`.

I would like to do `null` check on a variable which can be primitive or object. So I am trying to use `Optional` utility to do null check. I am getting `Optional can not be resolved`.

`if(Optional.ofNullable(${value}).orElse(null) != null) {};`

`${value}` will be mapped from java code.

Comment: what about : `if (value){}`

Comment: If you make it work, then `Optional.ofNullable(${value}).orElse(null)` is just a very roundabout way of getting the exact same value as `${value}`. In other words: that whole construct is pointless.

Comment: It's best to avoid using optional just for a null check

Answer (score 2):

`Optional` was introduced in Java 1.8 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

Groovy 2.4.12 uses Java 1.7 (here's the matric http://groovy-lang.org/download.html#requirements)

If you have Java 1.8+ installed, Groovy *should* be able to use `Optional`, provided it `java.util.*` or `java.util.Optional` was imported.

With the code sample you provided it is unclear what you're actually trying to accomplish, but, strictly speaking, `Optional` does not save you from checking for `null`, you just do it differently.

Comment: Thank you. I am able to solve my issue in a different way which is specific to my project.